# Мне нужен кто-нибудь, кто может расшифровать "Luraph Obfuscator" [закрыто]

Tags: lua, roblox

Мне прислали код но сам сценарий запутанный. Для игры ROBLOX которая использует Lua, код будет приведен ниже.Насколько я могу судить, запустив его, это может сработать. Но мне нужно было бы изменить сценарий, чтобы он заработал. Кто-нибудь знает, как расшифровать обфускациию?
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vestyx/PetSimulatorXAutoFarm/main/HasteFarm.lua

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.